# Redundant files after docpad generate --env static

Tags: docpad

I'm using the [Clean URLs Plugin](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/) and I end up having redundant files in my /out/ directory after `docpad generate --env static`: one content.html and the same in /content/index.html

I suppose that's a wrong behaviour? Does it result because `docpad run` creates the files for the non static behavious, and `docpad generate --env static` the other ones afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I was looking at a file where something went wrong. Now there are still the *redundant* html files at first sight, but the ones in the root redirect to the others. So all good. When I looked before for some reasons I caught a strange glitch.